# Sphinx - cannot filter by category using sql_attr_multi

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I am trying to filter by category in my events index - 
it is a many to many relationship and `event_category_event_rel`
is my pivot table. `view_event_search` is a mysql view 'denormalising'
my event data. It does not join the `event_category` table.

This is my config:

```
(...)
sql_query  = SELECT * FROM view_event_search 
             WHERE id <= (SELECT max_doc_id FROM search_indexes WHERE `index`='events_primary')

# Attribute config
sql_attr_uint      = user_id
sql_attr_timestamp = created_on
sql_attr_multi     = UINT categories FROM QUERY; SELECT event_id, event_category_id FROM event_category_event_rel ORDER BY event_id;
(...)
```

I am using PHP and filtering for the attribute as follows

```
$client->SetFilter('categories', array(1));
```

and get the following error:

```
Search Error: no such filter attribute 'categories'
```

Here is what I think I've understood:

1. In UINT categories FROM QUERY; the 'categories' is the attribute name.
2. and the sql query part must return the document id at index 0 and the filter value
   at index 1. Sphinx then matches the document id returned to the sql_query document id. If there is a duplicate document id (event_id) in the MVA then the value (event_category_id) is 'appended' to the values for that document.

Am I misunderstanding? and how do I filter by category?
Much appreciated!

Comment: My problem was a multitude of typos elsewhere in my system :/ Everyone has days when they feel like a noob I guess... Great to know that the multi attribute works like I thought from the beginning - super useful and (now) intuitive - Thanks again Sphinx Team!

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks fine. I suspect you havent correctly rebuilt the index after changing the config.

using indexer with --rotate is the best option.

Otherwise, shutdown, searchd, rebuild the index, and then start searchd again.

(other thing to check that the event_id is the first column in view_event_search, you probably have this, but its not clear from what you wrote, so just making sure)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I commented under the question that I had made a few typos :P multi attributes weren't so clear to me back then so I wasn't sure of its syntax which lead me to ask this question prematurely.